# delayed job process running as root on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, delayed-job, file-permissions

I have a Rails site which uses the [Delayed Job Gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to run a background task. The background task takes a PDF and converts it to a series of images.

The Rails app runs as 'nobody' and the delayed job process runs as 'root'.

The background task runs fine but a problem occurs when the Rails app tries to delete the file which was created by the delayed job process: I get a 'Permission denied' message.  So 'nobody' can't delete the file which was created by 'root'.

The problem can be fixed if I set the file/folder permissions with:

```
    chmod -R 755
```

But this does not affect new files.

I'm deploying my Rails app using Capistrano under the root account.

I'm quite the noob as a linux system admin.  Can you suggestion where I'm going wrong?

Many Thanks

Comment: I prefer to run my rails apps and delayed job using the same user called rails (or www, or anything else). You can tell capistrano to deploy with the user you want using set :user 'username', and i think that delayed job runs with the user that installed the gem.

Comment: Ah that bit 'delayed job runs with the user that installed the gem' is useful, I'll have to investigate that and try to get things working under a different account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem by following sailors advice: basically setup a new user for running the app and deployment.  Not sure if this will be useful to anyone else but here's how I transferred the site to a different user:

Steps

1. Create a new user called 'www'

   ```
   useradd -d /home/www -m
   passwd www
   ```
2. Give www control over the existing files:

   ```
   cd /path/to/site
   chmod -R g+ws *
   chgrp -R www *
   ```
3. Killed existing delayed_job process under root account
4. Updated the sites vhost to tell passenger which user to run as

   ```
   PassengerDefaultUser  www
   ```
5. Tell cap to deploy with user www in deploy.rb

   ```
   set :user, "www"
   ```

Now the delayed job process and the sites process run as 'www' which solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

delayed_job provides its own Capistrano recipe, which should be able to use to start/stop the server using the same user as your app. You basically just need to `require "delayed/recipes"` in your `deploy.rb` file. Then you can start/stop delayed_job remotely with `cap delayed_job:start` and `cap delayed_job:stop`.

More information [on the wiki](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Rails-3-and-Capistrano)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using this recipe when deploying but it runs the 'delayed_job' process under the root account.